# What's the relationship(difference) between probability space and probability density?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The first important concept in probability is probability space, which is a triple $(\Omega,F,P)$. $\Omega$ stands for samples, it is clear and unambiguous, $F$ stands for events it is also not difficult to understand. What confuses me is $P$. In here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space, it says $P$ is a probability function maps event to real value between [0,1]. But as we know, density function is a kind of best description to a distribution. I can't figure it out, what's the relationship between probability space and density function? For example, suppose we have two gaussians, $X(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$, $Y(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$, when could we say they are under the sampe space? Or, we could say different probability space just means different distribution , or versus. 
This question confuses me especially in stochastic process, because a stochastic process $X(t)$ can stand different random variables with the variation of $t$ but they all under the sampe probability space. I am not sure, can we say $X(t_1)=N(x|\mu_1,\sigma_1^2), X(t_2)=N(x|\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$, those two different distributions are in the same probability space?

Comment: Think of it in terms of measure.  Probability space is a measure space with total measure one.  Events are measurable subsets.  Probability of event is measure.  Usually when talking about distributions, the same measure space is used for all of them.  Specifically, for your last question,  the distributions are based on the same space.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation very much. As you said "when talking about distributions, the same measure space is used for all of them", what does this mean? Does it mean all the distributions are actually under the same space ? For example, single value Gaussian, multivariate Gaussian, Dirichlet distribution, Student distirubtion. If this is yes, how could we identify two different probability space? Thanks!

Comment: What I intended was about a problem involving more than one random variable and their relationships.  In most questions about probability, the underlying space is not imortant.  The events and the distributions are what matters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!